# Swipeable UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to implement a Swipeable `UISegmentedControl` in Swift. I have `UISegmenttedControl` view, but how can I make in swipeable like a tab bar in Android.

I have a git MIT licensed project [HMSegmentedControl](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl), but I am required to implement it standalone. I need a a simple guidance.

Comment: If the underlay view is scrollview (it should be), you can just simply get the percentage of the location over contentview and move the segment highlight view with that in `scrollViewDidScroll`

Comment: This question is too broad.  What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UISegmentControl` as Subview of `UIScrollView`

I'm using `UIStoryboard` to design my View. Please follow these steps.

Step 1: Add `UIScrollView` to your storyboard.

Step 2: The width of the `UIScrollView` should be of View's width, height as approx 60px.

Step 3: Add `UISegmentControl` with n Segments to the `UIScrollView`, the width of the `UISegmentControl` should be of 100*n px (You can calculate based on your requirements).

Step 4: Now, Add Outlet for `UIScrollView` in your ViewController.

Step 5: Add **contentsize** for the `UIScrollView`, following code in the `viewDidLoad` of your ViewController

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100*n, 60);
```

Please do your own customizations for `UISegmentControl`. I have tested the same & it is working for me.

This should work for you!